# iPad Application Comes Up in Portrait Orientation After Screen Unlock Regardless of Orientation on Screen Sleep

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios, orientation

I have my iPad application in landscape mode sitting at my desk. When the iPad's screen locks, I unlock the screen. When the application is shown again, the application is in portrait mode and will remain so until I pick up my iPad and move it around to reset the orientation.

Is there some sort of check that I should make to leave it in the orientation that it is in when the view appears?

Comment: After looking at this some more, when I debug my application coming back after a screen lock, my shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method is being called with a UIInterfaceOrientation of portrait, even though I haven't rotated the device. Then my shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is called again with the correct landscape orientation argument. I'm confused as to why it's being called with portrait first.

Answer (score 0):

You can try checking `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]` and then setting the correct orientation from there.

Comment: That's fine, but how would I set the orientation? From everything I gather, the methods in UIDevice are what you should use, but if you do use those methods then Apple will reject your application. Any other ideas?