# IPad application first comes in portrait mode and then in landscape mode after unlocking the screen which was in landscape mode at the time of locking

Tags: ios, ipad, screen-orientation, orientation-changes, screen-lock

Might be possible duplicate of :- [iPad Application Comes Up in Portrait Orientation After Screen Unlock Regardless of Orientation on Screen Sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755051/ipad-application-comes-up-in-portrait-orientation-after-screen-unlock-regardless) but it does not provide any solution.

My problem is I am working in landscape mode on iPad and I locks my screen. After that when I  unlocks, my screen first switch to portrait mode and then to landscape mode.
I don't know why it first switch to portrait mode.

Please if any one has face this problem before or know how to sort out this, help me .

Thanks in advance.

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: In your `Info.plist` file, what appears under `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad` (or `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations` if that doesn't exist)?

Comment: This parameter does not exist in my info.plist.Should I add this.

Comment: My application support both portrait and landscape mode.

Comment: Yes. If you're using Xcode 4, you can do this by going to your app's target and selecting the summary tab. if you scroll down you should see a section entitled "Supported Device Orientations", just select which orientations you want to support and it should appear in your `Info.plist`.

Comment: thanks Sherman Lo I sort out my problem my adding this parameter in info.plist and adding values to this parameter.I wish I could vote up and accept if you write your comment as a answer.Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Info.plist` file, make sure that `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad` (or `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations`) exists and has the portrait and landscape orientations your app supports are listed.